# How to put my docker container on a production server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

(I'm new with Docker and Django)

It's seem to me that what i'm tring to do is the basics, but i'm struggling.

I want to setup my production environment with docker on an Ubuntu server. I'm using django & django REST framework & mysql database to build my application.

I already have my 2 images :

- one for **django**
- one for **MySQL**

I also have my container on my computer which i can run it with :

```
docker-compose up
```

How to put my docker container on a production server ?

(It's maybe not this way i should do, i lets you guide me ;) )

Answer (score 1):

you need to do the same thing on the production server .
Install docker and docker compose .
Check or update the settings/code for production.
clone the code and run the docker command in the directory where docker compose is present.
configure nginx or apache as proxy.
Use this for reference -[deployment](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/django-docker-production-heroku/)